# Using "will" after "when" referring to the future

Tags: grammar, future, when

I'm going to send an email to a professor. There is a sentence that I think may be wrong because I'm not sure about using **will** after **when,** even though it obviously refers to the future.

> But definitely I would love to join to your team and I hope you have an open position **when I will** apply for the next year.

What are the rules here?

Comment: Jack. "Can you correct this?" is a proof-reading request. "What are the rules here?" is asking to know **how** it should be corrected. It's also more useful to future enquirers who might find this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Future tense usage: "When you see it ..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9599/future-tense-usage-when-you-see-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I would definitely love to join your team.  I hope you will have an open position when I apply next year.

Done with contractions: (A little less formal)

> But I'd definitely love to join your team.  I hope you'll have an open position when I apply next year.

Your word order is salvageable with punctuation.  I only removed 'and' as a mater of style.  Though 'will' and 'for the' are simply not needed.

> But, definitely, I would love to join to your team and I hope you have an open position when I will apply for the next year.

Done this way puts a pause before and after 'definitely' that highlights it for emphasis.  Which may or may not be what you want.

Some people discourage the over use of `I`.  Better not to make everything about you:

> If you have an open position when applications are accepted next year I would definitely be interested in joining your team.

Comment: This is not an answer, though. The question ***specifically*** asked "What are the rules here?"